# Skyrim un-saves when i unplug my xbox?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I unplug my xbox my saved games disappear and it makes me start over all the way to customizing my character what do I do ??

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your hard drive. Could be faulty

Comment: Does this only happen with Skyrim, or are your other games affected too? What about user profiles?

Comment: Actually, I have another theory. Unplug the Xbox then plug it in again. Boot it up and tell me what the date and time settings say.